# Firebase timestamps in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, timestamp

I'm trying to display Firebase timestamps with `toDate()` method, but I keep getting this 
[timestamp error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhqPk.png)

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Thu Feb 13 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

However, when I throw a `debugger` I can get it through the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAdQR.png) using `note.createdAt.toDate()`

How can I display it nicely on web?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
note.createdAt.toDate().toString()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please turn this into a more assertive and better explained answer. Otherwise you risk giving an impression of asking a clarification question, for which a comment should be used. I.e. this is not considered an answer and should hence not be written as an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead You could however [edit] and phrase for example like "In case your problem is that ... the solution is to ...., because ....". A "conditional" answer like that is helpful for users with similar problems if not the same.